# swagger-maven-plugin not producing keys and values, results in "empty" swagger.json

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, swagger

I am missing all the api and model attributes in my swagger.json file. I provided my pom.xml, the restcontroller with the annotations, the swagger.json and the stacktrace when using maven install

I configured the inputSpecs for the openapi-generator to use the swagger.json file, and the swagger-maven-plugin to generate from the given location com.mart.controller

pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mart11.backend</groupId>
      <artifactId>mart11-backend</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <properties>
    <nodeVersion>v14.16.0</nodeVersion>
    <npmVersion>7.6.0</npmVersion>

    <resources.generated>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources</resources.generated>
    <sources.generated>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</sources.generated>
    <swagger.json.output>${resources.generated}/swagger</swagger.json.output>
    <swagger.templates.folder>${project.basedir}/swagger</swagger.templates.folder>
    <swagger.ts.output>${sources.generated}/swagger</swagger.ts.output>
    <swagger.html.output>${project.build.directory}/classes/public/swagger</swagger.html.output>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
       <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
           <phase>initialize</phase>
            <configuration>
              <target>
                <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/classes"/>
              </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
              <groupId>${project.parent.groupId}</groupId>
              <artifactId>mart11-backend</artifactId>
              <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </artifactItem>
          </artifactItems>
          <outputDirectory>${resources.generated}</outputDirectory>
          <includes>swagger/**/*.mustache</includes>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>unpack mustache template</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${com.github.kongchen.swagger-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>Generate Swagger JSON</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <apiSources>
                <apiSource>
                  <schemes>https</schemes>
                  <basePath>localhost:8080/</basePath>
                  <springmvc>true</springmvc>
                  <locations>
                    <location>com.mart11.controller</location>
                  </locations>
                  <info>
                    <title>${project.name}</title>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                  </info>
                  <swaggerDirectory>${swagger.json.output}</swaggerDirectory>
                </apiSource>
              </apiSources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${openapi-generator-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>Generate TypeScript API</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <inputSpec>${swagger.json.output}/swagger.json</inputSpec>
              <generatorName>typescript-angular</generatorName>
              <output>${swagger.ts.output}</output>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

My RestController:

```
import com.mart11.dto.ReserveTableDTO;
import com.mart11.service.ReservationTableService;
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

@Api(value = "ReservationApi")
@RequestMapping
@RestController
public class ReservationController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReservationController.class);
    private final ReservationTableService reservationTableService;

    public ReservationController(ReservationTableService reservationTableService) {
        this.reservationTableService = reservationTableService;
    }

    @ApiOperation("Return account settings for the user")
    @GetMapping(value = "/api/getAllByDate", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ApiResponses({
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "", response = List.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "", response = SQLException.class)
    })
    public @ResponseBody
    List<ReserveTableDTO> getAllReservationsByDate(@RequestParam String date) throws SQLException {
        LOGGER.debug("JSON/REST GET call on /api/getAllByDate for date '{}'", date);
        return reservationTableService.getAllTablesByDate(date);
    }
}
```

The generated swagger.json file:

```
{
  "swagger" : "2.0",
  "info" : {
    "version" : "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",
    "title" : "Mart 11 Frontend"
  },
  "basePath" : "localhost:8080/",
  "schemes" : [ "https" ]
}
```

Maven install stacktrace:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:unpack (unpack mustache template) @ mart11-frontend ---
[INFO] Configured Artifact: com.mart11:mart11-backend:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:jar
[INFO] Unpacking C:\Users\aleks\mart11-reservation\mart11-backend\target\mart11-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\aleks\mart11-reservation\mart11-frontend\target\generated-resources with includes "swagger/**/*.mustache" and excludes ""
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- swagger-maven-plugin:3.1.7:generate (Generate Swagger JSON) @ mart11-frontend ---
[INFO] Reflections took 43 ms to scan 99 urls, producing 0 keys and 0 values 
[INFO] Reflections took 23 ms to scan 99 urls, producing 0 keys and 0 values 
[INFO] Reflections took 18 ms to scan 99 urls, producing 0 keys and 0 values 
[INFO] Reflections took 15 ms to scan 99 urls, producing 0 keys and 0 values 
[INFO] Reflections took 16 ms to scan 99 urls, producing 0 keys and 0 values 
[INFO] Reflections took 15 ms to scan 99 urls, producing 0 keys and 0 values 
[INFO] Reflections took 15 ms to scan 99 urls, producing 0 keys and 0 values 
[INFO] Reflections took 20 ms to scan 99 urls, producing 0 keys and 0 values 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- openapi-generator-maven-plugin:5.0.0:generate (Generate TypeScript API) @ mart11-frontend ---
[WARNING] C:\Users\aleks\mart11-reservation\mart11-frontend\target\generated-resources\swagger\swagger.json [0:0]: unexpected error in Open-API generation
org.openapitools.codegen.SpecValidationException: There were issues with the specification. The option can be disabled via validateSpec (Maven/Gradle) or --skip-validate-spec (CLI).
 | Error count: 1, Warning count: 0
Errors: 
    -attribute paths is missing

    at org.openapitools.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator.toContext (CodegenConfigurator.java:541)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator.toClientOptInput (CodegenConfigurator.java:568)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.plugin.CodeGenMojo.execute (CodeGenMojo.java:717)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
[ERROR] 
org.openapitools.codegen.SpecValidationException: There were issues with the specification. The option can be disabled via validateSpec (Maven/Gradle) or --skip-validate-spec (CLI).
 | Error count: 1, Warning count: 0
Errors: 
    -attribute paths is missing

    at org.openapitools.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator.toContext (CodegenConfigurator.java:541)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator.toClientOptInput (CodegenConfigurator.java:568)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.plugin.CodeGenMojo.execute (CodeGenMojo.java:717)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for mart11 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] mart11 ............................................. SUCCESS [  0.293 s]
[INFO] Mart 11 Backend .................................... SUCCESS [  2.369 s]
[INFO] Mart 11 Frontend ................................... FAILURE [  4.294 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```